# Python what is the fastest way to find the most common letter in a list of words?

Tags: python, list, artificial-intelligence, counter

I am trying to write an AI for hangman that guesses the word you are thinking of. After guessing a vowel correct, I want it to find the most common letter for the next letter guess. How can I do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: Find a word corpus, filter the words that has the correct length and have that vowel at the correct place.

Comment: You probably shouldn't concern yourself with what's "fastest" if all you're writing is a hangman game. The user isn't going to notice if it takes 0.001 seconds to respond instead of 0.00001 seconds. Write something that works, then optimize later if and only if you identify a bottleneck.

Comment: This may help: [How to quickly get the collection of words in a corpus (with nltk)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29272299/how-to-quickly-get-the-collection-of-words-in-a-corpus-with-nltk)

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be really fast, I'd write a `c` [extension](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html).

Using only python, there are many ways do do that. You can test a few and see which is the fastest. Because python's built-in functions are optimized, I'd try use them as much as I can instead of loops, so that's how I'd do it:

```
def commonLetter(words):
    joined = ''.join(words) # creating one string from all the words
    letterDict = {} # will contain the number of occurences for each letter
    def addToDict(letter):
        try: letterDict[letter] += 1
        except: letterDict[letter] = 1
    map(addToDict, joined) # applying addToDict to all the letters
    return max(letterDict.keys(), key=lambda letter: letterDict[letter])

words = [
    'Python', 'what', 'is', 'the',
    'fastest', 'way', 'to', 'find',
    'the', 'most', 'common', 'letter',
    'in', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words'
]
print commonLetter(words) # outputs 't'
```

You can also try:

```
def commonLetter(words):
    joined = ''.join(words) # creating one string from all the words
    tuples = map(lambda letter: (letter, joined.count(letter)), set(joined))
    return max(tuples, key=lambda tup: tup[1])[0]
```

Or:

```
def commonLetter(words):
    joined = ''.join(words) # creating one string from all the words
    return Counter(joined).most_common(1)[0][0]
```